# Bootstrap push pull maximum limit

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 blocks of data. First one having grid size of 10, second also size of 10 and third having size of 2.Can i pull the third grid 20 times to make it the 1st grid?

At first its like

[image]

then i want the result like

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
.a{
background:blue;
}
.b{
background:red;
}
.c{
background:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="c col-xs-12 col-sm-10">Graph</div>
<div class="b col-xs-12 col-sm-10">Meters</div>
<div class="a col-xs-12 col-sm-2">Buttons</div>


</div>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to put the buttons before graph in screen size greater than xs

Comment: Maybe if you share more details: code, images, etc

Comment: @ppaulojr i edited the question

Comment: No. Push and pull move the element horizontally by adjusting the `left` or `right` properties. They can't be used to change the order in which elements wrap on to a new line

Comment: @SexyTurnip Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @SexyTurnip Question edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two different set of buttons. One that will be placed before the graphs and will be visible only in larger that xs screens, and one the will be placed after the graphs and will only be visible in xs screens.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="a col-xs-12 col-sm-2 hidden-xs">Buttons</div>
    <div class="c col-xs-12 col-sm-10">Graph</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 hidden-xs"></div>
    <div class="b col-xs-12 col-sm-10">Meters</div>
    <div class="a col-xs-12 col-sm-2 visible-xs">Buttons</div>
</div>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxx4sbzz/)